# Powershell Core + Pester - Separating tests from src

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, powershell-core, pester

#### Question:

What would be the best way to import functions to tests that don't reside in the same directory?

Example

```
 src
       Get-Emoji.ps1
 test
       Get-Emoji.Tests.ps1
```

#### Inb4

- Pester documentation[1] suggests test files are placed in the same directory as the code that they test. No examples of alternatives provided.
- Pester documentation[2] suggests dot-sourcing to import files. Only with examples from within same directory
- Whether breaking out tests from the src is good practice, is to be discussed elsewhere
- Using Powershell Core for cross platform support on different os filesystems (forward- vs backward slash)

---

[1] [File placement and naming convention](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/file-placement-and-naming#common-convention)

> Pester considers all files named .Tests.ps1 to be test files. This is the default naming convention that is used by almost all projects.
>
> Test files are placed in the same directory as the code that they test. Each file is called as the function it tests. This means that  for a function Get-Emoji we would have Get-Emoji.Tests.ps1 and Get-Emoji.ps1 in the same directory. What would be the best way to referencing tests to functions in Pester.

[2] [Importing the tested functions](https://pester.dev/docs/usage/importing-tested-functions#importing-the-tested-functions)

> Pester tests are placed in .Tests.ps1 file, for example Get-Emoji.Tests.ps1. The code is placed in Get-Emoji.ps1.
>
> To make the tested code available to the test we need to import the code file. This is done by dot-sourcing the file into the current scope like this:
>
> Example 1
>
> ```
> # at the top of Get-Emoji.Tests.ps1
> BeforeAll { 
>     . $PSScriptRoot/Get-Emoji.ps1
> }
> ```
>
> Example 2
>
> ```
> # at the top of Get-Emoji.Tests.ps1
> BeforeAll { 
>     . $PSCommandPath.Replace('.Tests.ps1','.ps1')
> }
> ```

Comment: Not sure I understand what the issue is. Is dot sourcing not an option?

Comment: Sure, dot sourcing works. But how would be the best way? 
An alternative for example could be 
 `. ([IO.Path]::Combine($PSEditor.Workspace.Path, "path/to/function/Get-Emoji.ps1"))`

Comment: Another dimension to also consider is absolute vs relative paths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to keep my tests together in a single folder that is one or two parent levels away from where the script is (which is usually under a named module directory and then within a folder named either Private or Public). I just dot source my script or module and use `..` to reference the parent path with `$PSScriptRoot` (the current scripts path) as a point of reference. For example:

- Script in `\SomeModule\Public\get-something.ps1`
- Tests in `\Tests\get-something.tests.ps1`

```
BeforeAll { 
    . $PSScriptRoot\..\SomeModule\Public\get-something.ps1    
}
```

Use forward slashes if cross platform compatibility is a concern, Windows doesn't mind if path separators are forward or backslashes. You could also run this path through `Resolve-Path` first if you wanted to be certain a valid full path is used, but I don't generally find that necessary.